# How to do push for new repository?

Tags: macos, git, github

I created new repository (git@github.com:derkode/ForvoClient.git) and did SSH Key, then:

```
git config --global user.email "my_email@mail.com"
git config --global user.name "my_nickname"
git config --global push.default simple

git init
git add *
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:derkode/ForvoClient.git
```

But after: **git push -u origin master**

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed
>   to push some refs to 'git@github.com:derkode/ForvoClient.git' hint:
>   Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git
>   pull') hint: before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about
>   fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

What is it?

Comment: The error message tells you: your local version is behind the remote version. It tells you to merge the remote changes (`git pull`) and then try pushing again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repo on GitHub already has a commit.

https://github.com/derkode/ForvoClient

This is normal when you create a repo with a README file.

You can fix this either by force pushing your local repo to GitHub, but you will lose the README file this way:

```
git push -u origin master -f
```

Or, you can merge the version on GitHub into yours and then push it back:

```
git pull origin master
git push -u origin master
```

Or, as [@xbonez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315828/xbonez) suggested, rebase your version on top of GitHub's version:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: hours on this, and your post helped me get local files to my bitbucket account. my many thanks! i will revisit the whole process to get comfortable with it, and have bookmarked this post in case i have more questions. 

i had gotten msgs saying the git rebase did not work, and to try a "git rebase --continue", but first had to do a "git add .". after that your above 3 git commands put code in my online repo. thx!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the commit that Github created for you with the README file, follow `janos`'s answer. If you want to keep that commit, and push yours over it, simply pull down those changes and then push:

```
git fetch origin && git rebase origin/master && git push origin master
```